# Ожидание работы python функции определенное время и передача управления в другую функцию

Tags: python-3.x, asyncio, threading

нужен совет по работе скрипта.

```
def f1():
    return int(input("Введите число: "))

def f():
    print("Работа функции в цикле неопределенное время")

def main():
    # как тут реализовать ожидание выполнения функции f1() в течении 5 секунд?
    # инече присваиваем none(либо значение по умолчанию)
    n = f1()
    if n == 5:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        # а в данную функцию необходимо передать управление,
        # т.к. она будет работать в цикле неопределенное время
        f()
    # работа функции продолжается и тут завершается
    print("Завершение работы функции")

main()
```

Python последней версии. Два вопроса, они в комментариях. Возможно ли это реализовать через asyncio?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call

Comment: С передачей управления одной функции в другую можно реализовать через потоки. А вот с "n = f1()" все равно не понятно. Нужно что бы как только f1() выдаст результат, программа продолжила работу. Может передать выполнение этого блока в поток, опрашивать его результат через wile о результате выполнения, если в течении 5 секунд результат нет, гасим этот поток и продолжаем работу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Суть вопроса сводила к тому, что бы чат бот на aiogram периодически отправлял сообщение. Конечно я не правильно поставил вопрос, но решон он был следующим образом

```
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor #, types
from bot.config import load_config
from app import data


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Загружаем из .env настройки, шаблон настроек в .env_shablon
config = load_config(".env")
bot = Bot(token=config.tg_bot.token, parse_mode='HTML')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


if __name__=="__main__":
    from bot.handlers import dp # Команда start
    from bot.handlers_menu import dp # События на нажатия меню
    from bot.handlers_user import dp
    from bot.handlers_echo import dp

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(data.napominanie())
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```